# How to stop np.vectorize from printing error that I have caught

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

I have recently moved from Python 2 to Python 3, and encountered an issue I don't think happened in Python 2 (but I'm not completely sure.)

The following code prints out a warning (but does not stop running):

```
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def reciprocal(num):
    try:
        return 1/num
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

reciprocal(0)

#prints: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in long_scalars
```

even though I'm dealing with the error just fine in my function.

How do I stop this warning from printing/happening?

Comment: The important difference is that the vectorized function raises `RuntimeWarning`, which your `except` won't catch.

Comment: As an aside, you almost certainly shouldn't be using `np.vectorize` for this, because it is very inefficient.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What's a better way to make it so that a function is called element-wise? This is similar to code I've written for a neural net using np.vectorize so faster would be better.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do, but `np.vectorize` is just a vanilla Python for-loop. But you should lean on `numpy`s vectorized behavior. So, for this particular function, you should just do `rec = 1/arr; rec[np.isinf(rec)] =  0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `suppressWarning` decorator presented in another solution works, it may be a little bit too allowing, in that it just does not report warnings at all. I would argue that, at least sometimes, it is better to make the warnings explicit, by promoting them to errors and then handle them as such. That can easily be done, using the `warnings` module:

```
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('error')

@np.vectorize
def reciprocal(num):
    try:
        return 1/num
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # Now we end up here.
        return 0

reciprocal(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a decorator to suppress warnings on a function. It uses the same strategy as [Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) from the Python docs.

```
import warnings

def suppressWarnings(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Then, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

@suppressWarnings
@np.vectorize
def reciprocal(num):
    try:
        return 1/num
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

reciprocal(0)
```

and it won't print out any warnings.

Comment: After using this decorator, my neural net code would no longer work. I didn't have the time to figure out why, but I just wanted to let other people know that this should probably not be used as a solution. For the example presented it does seem to work though.